# How to get second option value of a select input?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, select

There are three select inputs in my form :

```
...
<tr>
            <td><b><?php echo _getText("service.OD.tbr_title.vondrona");?></b></td>
            <td>
            <select id="vondrona" name="vondrona" onchange="rafraichirListBoxs($(this).val());" >
              <option value="">Select all</option>
              <?php
              for ($r=0 ; $r<$data['vondrona']['cnt']; $r++) {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $data['vondrona'][$r]['id_vondrona']; ?>"><?php echo $data['vondrona'][$r]['lib_vondrina']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo _getText("service.OD.tbr_title.sokajy");?></b></td>
            <td>
            <select id="sokajy" name="sokajy" onchange="rafraichirKarazana($(this).val());">
              <option value="">Select all</option>
              <?php
              for ($r=0 ; $r<$data['sokajy']['cnt']; $r++) {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $data['sokajy'][$r]['id_sokajy']; ?>"><?php echo $data['sokajy'][$r]['lib_sokajy']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo _getText("service.OD.tbr_title.type");?></b></td>
            <td>
            <select id="karazana" name="karazana">
              <option value="">Select all</option>
              <?php
              for ($r=0 ; $r<$data['karazana']['cnt']; $r++) {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $data['karazana'][$r]['id_karazana']; ?>"><?php echo $data['karazana'][$r]['lib_karazana']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
...
```

There is a master-detail relationship between these inputs : vondrona is the main master, then sokajy and last karazana.

Javascripts :

```
function rafraichirListBoxs(id_vondrona) {
    var donne = "id_vondrona="+id_vondrona;
    var html = $.ajax({
            data: donne   ,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>service/ListerSokajyAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;
    $('#sokajy').html(html);

    donne = "id_sokajy="+$('#sokajy').val(); // this causes the bug , how to get the second option value ( the option after the "Select all" first option ) ?
    html = $.ajax({
            data: donne   ,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>service/ListerKarazanaAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;
    $('#karazana').html(html);

    donne = "type_id="+$('#karazana').val();
    html = $.ajax({
            data: donne   ,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>service/ListerVokatraAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;
    $('#produit').html(html);
}
```

The problem is with the first option "Select all" which is not from database. As mentionned in the javascript function I want to get first detail option value related to the selected master select input.

So how to get the option value just after the "Select All" option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try

```
//As the index starts from 0, the second item index will be 1.
var secondOption = document.getElementById('ddl').options[1].value;
```

OR you can try

```
var secondOptionValue = $("#selbox option:eq(1)").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

For e.g, consider your first drop down,
You can get the value of second option using javascript as follows:

```
var dd = document.getElementById('vondrona');
var value = dd.options[1].value;
```

or using jQuery:

```
var value= $('#vondrona option:eq(1)').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to have the second option, you can get it via jQuery like this:

```
donne = "id_sokajy="+$("#sokajy option:eq(1)").val();
```